# useState is setting nothing and if I add that value to the list of dependencies my component triggers infinite re-render loop

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to set an array of movies I get from Nodejs, that part is working correctly because the response is OK, but when I use useState to set the array in my component it's like it is not triggering the re-render. Sorry if my English is not perfect, I'm from Argentina but I could not find any article that helps me in my language.

Favorites component shows the Favorites movies of the logged User

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Modal from "../Modal";

const Favorites = ({user, favMovies}) =>{
    const [myList,setMyList] = useState(favMovies);
    const [favsList,setFavsList] = useState([]);

    const getData = async() =>{
        const response = await axios.post('/api/favs',{favMovies:myList});
        const data = response.data.favsList;
        console.log(data);
        setFavsList(data);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        setMyList(favMovies);
        if(myList){
            getData();
        }
    },[])

}

export default Favorites;
```

App component have the router and like you can see, sends the favMovies as a prop to the Favorites component, this array called favMovies is an array of Id which I run through to get one by one the movies of the user

```
function App() {
  const [user,setUser] = useState({});
  const [favsList,setFavsList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const loggedinUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
    if(loggedinUser){
      setUser(JSON.parse(loggedinUser));
      console.log(user);
    }
  },[])

  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar {...user} setUser={setUser}/>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path='/' element={<ListMovies url={'/api'}/>} />
        <Route path='/popular' element={<ListMovies url={'/api/popular'} />} /> 
        <Route path='/movie/:id' element={<InfoMovie {...user}/>} />
        <Route path='/contact' element={<Modal msg='Acirca de nos'/>} />
        <Route path='/login' element={<Login setUser={setUser}/>} />
        <Route path='/register' element={<Register/>}/>
        <Route path='/favs' element={<Favorites user={user} favMovies={user.favMovies}/>}/>
        <Route path='*' element={<Modal msg='No hubo coincidencias de ruta'/>} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I would be really thankful if someone could help me or already was through this problem, greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

1.Passing favMovies as props to the Favorites component instead of storing it as the component's state is more appropriate. When a component's props change, React will automatically re-render the component. Therefore, you can remove the myList state and use favMovies directly in the getData function.

2.In the useEffect hook, add favMovies as a dependency. This way, the effect will run whenever the favMovies prop changes.

3.In the App component, make sure that you are setting the user state correctly and passing user.favMovies as the favMovies prop to the Favorites component:

```
 const Favorites = ({ user, favMovies }) => {
      const [favsList, setFavsList] = useState([]);
    
      const getData = async () => {
        const response = await axios.post("/api/favs", { favMovies: favMovies });
        const data = response.data.favsList;
        console.log(data);
        setFavsList(data);
      };
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (favMovies) {
          getData();
        }
      }, [favMovies]);
    
    
    export default Favorites;
```

Comment: thanks, I was doubting between use useState to define myList or use the property send by the parent component, this worked fine

Comment: Just not use props as default value of useState(), It will make the logic of the components more complex.